# Dragon NaturallySpeaking writes "{Gauche 13}{Maj+Droite}{Maj+Gauche}..." when I select a word

Tags: dragon-naturally-speaking

This 15-second video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTdWTsFmzQE shows the issue. I say "we are going to eat", then I want to select "going" and Dragon writes the following:

> we are going to eat.{Gauche 13}{Maj+Droite}{Maj+Gauche}{Maj+Droite
>   6}{Maj+Gauche 6}{Maj+Droite}{Maj+Gauche}{Maj+Droite 5}

The issue disappears when I restart Dragon. But why does this issue appear sometime?

Note that Gauche and Droite are French words for Left and Right. Although I used Dragon in English in the video, my "core" version of Dragon is French, and for whatever reason Dragon outputs those French words even when using my English profile.

Comment: Does it do this when entering text in any application or just Chrome?

Comment: In any application.

Answer (score 1):

> The issue disappears when I restart Dragon. But why does this issue
>   appear sometimes?

Can't tell why this happens exactly, but Dragon outputs the keypresses required to select the given word as text. It appears that Dragon is not correctly processing your command. Instead of parsing it as a command, it is being parsed as text. A classical bug. The underlying reason is probably only known to the programmers of Dragon. All you can do is isolate the contexts in which the error appears and try to avoid them.

As for possible solutions:

1. Try creating a new profile.
2. Try using Dragon on a different computer.
3. Verify that you are using an application with Full Text Control (FTC, check is green). Standard applications that offer Full Text Control are Word, Outlook and Internet Explorer.
4. If you are working in Gmail in Chrome or Firefox, you need to make sure that the Rich Internet Application plugin is activated. You can do this in your Chrome extensions. (Dragon installs it automatically. I keep it deactivated because it makes Chrome crash quite frequently.)
5. Try using the Dication Box.
6. Dictate into DragonPad or Notepad and see if the issue appears there. These are the two applications best supported by Dragon, especially DragonPad which was literally made to work with Dragon. If it does not, use these applications to create your text and the create a command to transfer the text to you desired application.

If the issue appears in Full Text Control apps: 
You can submit a ticket to Nuance and hope that they will fix it in a new version or in a patch. Alternately, create a new profile and see if it happens there. If it doesn't happen there, you can just export your vocabulary and commands to the new profile.

Some background on what is being displayed: When you issue a command in some applications, Dragon will attempt to calculate the distance between the word and where you are now in the text. It will cross that distance and select the word by simulating keypresses like <kbd>Shift-Right</kbd> or <kbd>Shift-Left</kbd>, just as you would with your keyboard. (Dragon does this with some additional jiggling that I don't quite follow, but I suspect it is to avoid issues with spaces before or after words. It probably even does more than this command, but this it was you see anyway. This is all in the background, hidden in the source code.)

I think this behaviour occurs only in applications that do not offer FTC because Dragon cannot "see" the text and needs to calculate the distance differently.

If you do scripting for Dragon as I've done, you will recognize the expressions like `{Maj+Droite 5}` as commands to send keystrokes (there are several varieties).

> for whatever reason Dragon outputs those French words even when using my English profile

As for the French: This is tied to the language of your operating system. And indeed the French versions will display the keys in French (in German versions it is in German).

Comment: Thanks, I'm indeed mostly interested to understand why the issue appears so that I can try to avoid it as much as possible. The issue has happened on any of my Dragon profile. Filling a bug is a hassle with Nuance ([Nuance even used to charge for it](http://www.speechcomputing.com/node/3545), can you believe it?), I usually go with workarounds.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I've changed the answer quite a lot. Please check if the issue appears in Full Text Control programs like Word or Outlook, too. Dragon was made to work better with some applications than with others.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try next time the issue appears and let you know!

Comment: Indeed, the issue only happens in applications without Full Text Control. It is still a mystery why the issue appears sometime in the first place though, I still haven't found the root of that. Indeed it corresponds to commands to send keystrokes (I'm also writing "advanced scripting" for voice commands, although I don't find the scripting language very advanced, Nuance doesn't seem to care much about custom commands).